# JQuery Mobile Dynamic Page using .load makes me have to Refresh to see content

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load page content across domains and load the result into a div. When I visit the page the first time, no content loads. When I refresh, it works fine and works fine every time I visit the page after that no matter which article I view. Do I need to find a way to do the load after the DOM has loaded completely?

Link to like this: /news_item.php?article_id=4379

---- news_item.php -----

```
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
   $("#gametime").load('proxy.php?url=http://www.newsdomain.com/news/icehogs/?article_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["article_id"] ?>  .article', function () {

     $("#gametime a").replaceWith( function() { return $(this).text(); });
     $("#gametime .links").replaceWith('');
     $("#gametime .social").replaceWith('');

 });

});
```

----- proxy.php ------

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do, put your code into the `$(function(){});` event.

Comment: it's all in the pageinit function right now.. Do I need a different function?

Comment: I added  data-ajax="false"  to the links to this page and everything seems to load fine now. I think.

Comment: It's fine if you don't want to use ajax there.

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript file inside page div, eg.:

```
<div id="pageid" data-role="page">  
    <script src="javascriptfilename"></script>
    <div data-role="content"></div> 
</div>
```